# Get response of message queue inside rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, rabbitmq

I have a rails controller (say in application A) whose response is dependent on data from another application (say application B).

I am using RabbitMq for inter application communication.

I can not render a response from the controller till the time the queue worker gets a response from application B. So currently when I get an HTTP call on application A, I publish to application B through a RabbitMq queue to fetch the required data. I am listening for the response of application  B on a queue created by 'sneakers' gem. I want to receive this fetched data from 'sneakers' queue inside the controller of application A.

So the question is how can I wait for the RabbitMq, queue response inside the controller? 
And also if I am able to wait for the response inside controller, how will I figure out which queue response is for which HTTP call.

Answer (score 0):

To address the second issue, you can send a randomly generated string along with the request you send to application B. And the application B while responding will also send the same string that it got with the request. So the controller A will know for which request the response is.

Now coming to the first question, I think rabbitmq is not the correct tool to do such a thing. Even if you could wait for the message, It will be a very slow affair. compared to that a better way would be to expose application B as an API. It will increase the speed of the application by many times.

If API is not an option you can look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882572/how-to-create-a-rabbitmq-consumer-on-a-ruby-on-rails-web-app) on how to create a consumer.